# Remove a group on strings from an object in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

So, I have the following

`removed_caps = self.user.caps.reject { |c| c == 'test' || c == 'test1'}`

I want to have test and test1 as configs so that I can add to these in the future.

so something like:

```
caps_to_remove = ENV['BLACK_LIST']
split_caps_to_remove = caps_to_remove.split(' ')
puts split_caps_to_remove -->>> ["test", "test1"]
```

How do I incorporate `split_caps_to_remove` in the original code?

Thanks.

Comment: If both are arrays: `user.caps - split_caps_to_remove`

Comment: BTW, `removed_caps` sounds as if it contains the caps that were removed, whereas it contains the caps that remain.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to:

```
removed_caps = self.user.caps.reject { |c| split_caps_to_remove.include?(c) }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Fixed-String Methods

Assuming you have some variables defined as in the example below, then you can use [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-delete) or [String#delete!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-delete-21) as a faster way to remove your unwanted characters. Consider:

```
caps = ENV['BLACKLIST']='TE'
str1, str2 = 'TEST', 'TEST1'

[str1, str2].map { _1.delete caps }
#=> ["S", "S1"]
```

Fewer methods in a chain are often faster, and String methods that operate on a fixed String are often and order of magnitude faster Regexp-related methods like #gsub or iterating over a collection.

### See Also

You didn't provide your actual input or calling code, but in newer Ruby versions (including 3.1.2) there are some other related methods (some with bang methods, which are both useful and faster if you aren't using frozen strings) that may also help:

- [String#delete_prefix](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix)
- [String#delete_suffix](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-delete_suffix)
- [String#downcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-downcase)
- [String#swapcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-swapcase)